# Flash message is not shown when trying to use getFlashBag()

Tags: symfony

Hello friendly people,

I am following a tutorial on Symfony, in which I try to display a flash message, but even though I followed the instructions, no flash message is shown.
Here is my function viewAction in my AdvertController:

```
public function viewAction($id)

{
  return $this->render('NeoPlatformBundle:Advert:view.html.twig', array('id' => $id));
}
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
  $session = $request->getSession();
  $session->getFlashBag()->add('info' , 'This is a flash message');
  $session->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'This is a second flash message');
  return $this->redirectToRoute('neo_platform_view', array('id' => 5));
}
```

When I go to 
    http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/platform/add
I only get this:
[image: no flash message]

My view.html.twig is as follows:

```
{# src/Neo/PlatformBundle/Resources/view/Advert/view.html.twig #}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Display of the announcement {{id}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Display of the announcement n°{{id}}!</h1>
    <div>
        {#We display all flash messages, whose name is "info" #}
        {% for message in app.session.flashbag.get('info') %}
          <p>Flash message : {{message}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check `intercept-redirects` option in profiler ?

Comment: Its seems you have enabled `intercept_redirects` to debug redirection. you can disable it or click on the visible link to go to the desired page.

Comment: Oh Thank you, that was it!